# Validation get's triggered even when custom validation rule is false. Why?

Tags: cakephp

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Announcement extends AppModel {

    public $validate = array(
        'id' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                                ),
            'numeric' => array(
                'rule' => array('numeric'),
            ),
        ),
        'enabled' => array(
            'numeric' => array(
                'rule' => array('numeric'),
            ),
            'boolean' => array(
                'rule' => array('boolean'),
            ),
        ),
        'firstPageEnterDate' => array(
            'datetime' => array(
                'rule' => 'compareDates',
                'message' => 'attention to data interval',
            ),
        ),
        'firstPageLeaveDate' => array(
            'datetime' => array(
                'rule' => array('datetime'),
            ),
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
            ),
        )
    );

    public function compareDates() {
        if ($this->data[$this->alias]['enabled'] == 1) {
            return $this->data[$this->alias]['firstPageEnterDate'] < $this->data[$this->alias]['firstPageLeaveDate'];
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is:
It displays the validation message set on `firstPageEnterDate`, regardless, if
`$this->data[$this->alias]['enabled'] == 1` or not.

Please note that this condition:
`$this->data[$this->alias]['enabled'] == 1` is not always true. But even when it's false, so the contents inside don't run, still the message appears.

So, it seems that, if Cake sees a `rule` enabled and a `message`, regardless what is inside `rule`, it triggers the validation message associated!

Any clue why?

```
'firstPageEnterDate' => array(
            'datetime' => array(
                'rule' => 'compareDates',
                'message' => 'attention to data interval',
            ),
```

Comment: Where is 'enable' supposedly being added (or not) to your data?

Comment: Why dont you use isset()?

Comment: @dave just updated with the enable added.

Comment: @MoyedAnsari isset will never be true, because the array at the time the model is called will never have "enable" inside it. I'm not sure when he checks the enable. But the database gets the value 0 or 1 properly. :s

Comment: @Dave True being told. I have no clue where should the enable supposedly being added to the data array. I've generate this model using the bake command line. That model has some rules associated with the database field it encounters, and based on that he validates. How and where that occurs I can't say. Fairly new to cakephp here. But all fields are present as array elements, except, that "enable". :(

Comment: I've updated my question. `enabled` being there or not, is no longer the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return `true` in `compareDates()`  if it is valid -- or if you don't want to check it because that counts as valid.

```
public function compareDates() {
    if ($this->data[$this->alias]['enabled'] != 1) return true; // we don't want to check
    return $this->data[$this->alias]['firstPageEnterDate'] < $this->data[$this->alias]['firstPageLeaveDate'];
}
```

You can also check in `beforeValidate()` callback the value of `enabled` and unset that validation rule from there.

Comment: @tigrand - that worked perfectly. However, I don't understand the logic behind it. Why, do we need to return true, and why does that mean that "we don't want to check"? Why: `if ($this->data[$this->alias]['enabled'] == 1)` is not enough? Care to explain? Thank you very much.

Comment: Because not returning anything returns a falsey value (NULL), so a check of `if (compareDates())` will fail, and the validation rule will fail. Validation rules have three returns values, TRUE if it is valid, FALSE if invalid, or String if it fails and you want to provide a custom error message from within the custom validation method.